# Calculate percentages of intersected layers

Tags: qgis, shapefile, field-calculator, shape-area

I have two shape layers in QGIS. Layer A shows the geometry of districts in Berlin. Layer B shows water protection areas in Berlin. The different areas/ geometries of layer B can cross multiple districts.

I would like to know what percentage of the total area in each district is covered by water protection areas. After using the tool Intersect I already calculated "area of water protection / total area of district * 100" but that didn't make any sense cause I only want to calculate with the water area whis is contained in the district, not the whole geometry.

[image: Berlin district outlines & water protection areas (in blue)]

Comment: `$area/"district-area"*100` as operation on the intersected water protection areas.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this expression on a field in Layer A.

```sql
area(
    intersection(
        @geometry, 
        aggregate('Layer B', 'collect', @geometry)
    )
) / area(@geometry) * 100
```

[image]